# where are the build logs created when gcloud app deploy fails

Tags: node.js, gcloud

Quick: where can I find the deployment logs for a node deploy which fails?

Setup: windows 10 box developing a node.js website. the website runs locally, and has deployed successfully with the same package stack (body-parser, express, firebase, firebase-tools, path, pug)

```
Google Cloud SDK 134.0.0
app-engine-python 1.9.40
bq 2.0.24
bq-win 2.0.24
core 2016.11.07
core-win 2016.11.07
gcloud
gsutil 4.22
gsutil-win 4.20
windows-ssh-tools 2016.05.13
```

The last few lines of the deploy output shows a core dump and timeout ends the deploy and how the latest gcloud update gacked up the logging output.

```
[91mnpm[0m[91m WARN using --force I sure hope you know what you are doing.
[0m
> group-coms@0.0.1 install /app
> npm install --force
[91mAborted (core dumped)
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [4] DEADLINE_EXCEEDED
```

Oh yes, when it failed earlier today, I moved the folder to the root of the drive testing the 'too long a path' theory and it deployed successfully a couple of times. I haven't added or renamed any files since then, I have tried reloading all the node_modules to no avail.

```
# [START app_yaml]
runtime: nodejs
vm: true
# [END app_yaml]
```

I changed the yamal file to comply with [upgrading#appyaml_changes](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/go/upgrading#appyaml_changes) and the deploy completed successfuly... I would still like to know more about how I can monitor the build process..

Comment: This might be npm stalling. It happens sometimes. Try running npm with the `-dd` or `-ddd` flags?

Comment: I'm using gcloud to run npm on the server, so I assume I can't set an npm flag that is going to be used on the back end. from gcloud app deploy